# CakePhp does not work in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, cakephp, ubuntu-14.04, postgresql-9.3

I have installed cakephp v2.4.6 in Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) and database is PostgreSQL. The same system works fine in Windows environment but after I transfer it into Ubuntu, it shows some issues.

1. The CSS does not work. No color and the login screen alignment change.
2. After login, an error says "the requested url was not found in the server" came.

Some forum ask us to change the config file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf`. But I could not find any `default.conf` file.

Please guide. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the Apache logs? Are the permissions set correctly on the files and directories?

Comment: Yes. I gave full permission actually.

Comment: This was reposted to http://askubuntu.com/q/513273/75715 without a link or any comment. That can waste everyone's time - splits useful answers etc. Please delete the other one. If you think this should be migrated, flag it and ask a mod to migrate. Especially when there's already an answer.

Comment: Also "some forum"? Er... link? Details? How exactly did you "transfer it into Ubuntu"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely, it's an issue with htaccess / mod_rewrite.

Can you see the css if you go to http://example.com/app/webroot/css/my_file.css? If so, it's a mod_rewrite issue.

Here's some stuff to try:

Enable mod_rewrite: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

There will be some relevant file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`. It might be `default.conf`, or `000-default.conf` or it might be named after your site. But there should be some relevant file there, and you'll need to edit it.

You'll need to ensure the following options are present in that file (note: be careful - your Directory may be slightly different - eg `/var/www/html` or something else. If it differs, don't change it):

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Lastly, restart apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`

See this article for more detail: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite

Comment: Mr. Joshua.paling. Thank you so much. I do have 000-default.conf file but there is nothing like Directory written in that file. I copy the code you gave and it work as a charm. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help. If the answer was correct, you should consider marking it as such - so that others know for future, and so I get the rep ;)

Comment: Why didnt you tell use Where to put that code ? Below old code ? Before ? In between ?