# CakePhp missing controller error in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: cakephp-2.3, ubuntu-14.04, postgresql-9.3

My next question is based on my previous question from:
[CakePhp does not work in Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378673/cakephp-does-not-work-in-ubuntu-14-04?noredirect=1). Currently the CSS and login page works fine but when I click the link that I created, an error saying "missing controller" appear. The controller is there in my Controller folder and file name is also correct. I have no problem using it in Windows environment and as I'm new to Ubuntu, I really need help.

Thank you.

Comment: What URL are you sent to when you click the link?

Comment: This is the index URL which works fine: http://localhost/eNCR/Users. This is the link URL which says missing controller: http://localhost/eNCR/Portusers

Comment: It means after login, the page appear without any problem but whenever i click on the link, it says missing controller but the controller is there. Only the index page works

Comment: is debug turned on? Do you see a message saying "please create the file..."? If so, please post that message.

Comment: (Or post a full screenshot if you're comfortable with that)

Comment: I am really sorry Mr. Joshua. Its my mistake. Today I learned that in Windows, the cakephp script is not case sensitive. Example, my file name in Windows is "portuserscontrol.php" but after migrate into Ubuntu, the controller file name must change to "PortusersController.php". Sorry to trouble u and thank you so much for your help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: no worries! You should answer your own question, so others in future know what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mr. joshua.paling, I learned that in Windows, the cakephp script is not case sensitive. Example, my file name in Windows is "portuserscontrol.php" but after migrate into Ubuntu, the controller file name must change to "PortusersController.php".